# Google Fonts HTTPS issue

Tags: css, google-font-api

I have a valid SSL for my website. All pages are working fine with HTTPS. But in Home page I have included the google fonts api. I am trying to include the following lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova" type="text/css" />
```

But getting error as follows
**We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. Thats all we know.** When I open the url in browser https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proxima+Nova its working fine

Comment: But when I opened that link it's showing error 403.

Comment: Google says: `This font family is not available on Google Fonts.` for Proxima Nova.

Comment: proxima nova is not a free font and hence the error.

Comment: Thank you guys.. I am also assuming its a licensed version. http://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/proxima-nova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxima nova is a premium found. We can download from

> http://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/proxima-nova